# Java TCP How do you read a sent stream size (header) and keep reading based upon that size

Tags: java, tcp

Given the following pseudo code. how would I do read in the given data

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [DataInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html) to make your life easy.

```
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
short myShortStreamSize = in.readShort();
byte[] payload = new byte[myShortStreamSize];
in.readFully(payload);
```

Comment: @EJP It was my assumption he was the down voter. Equally, Why are you concerned about my response?

Answer (score 1):

`Socket` has a `getInputStream()` method. You would use the returned `InputStream` and read `myShortStreamSize` of bytes from it into a `byte[]`, convert that into a int/long representing your payload size and then read into another, larger, `new byte[payloadSize]`, the payload itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [JBBP](https://code.google.com/p/java-binary-block-parser/)

```
@Bin class Struct { byte [] payload; }
@Bin class ParsedStream { Struct [] structs; }
ParsedStream parsed = JBBPParser.prepare("structs[_] { ushort size; byte [size] payload; }").parse(theInStream).mapTo(ParsedStream.class);
```