# How to unpack/extract low-order and high-order value from a Byte array element

Tags: java, sockets, arrays, bytebuffer

I'm new to bit manipulation and I'm receiving data via a socket connection.

Data received is populated in a byte buffer, size is 8.

The number of data fields is 5.

The data/fields are variable length.  So, it appears two of data/fields are combined as one byte.

`Sent dataset1:  1, 0, 0, 2, 22`
`Sent dataset2:  1, 0, 0, 2, 500`
`Example data received: [1, 0, -128, 22] or [1,0,-127, -12]`

From the example byte array elements total 4 when 5 data items was sent over a socket.
How can I `parse/unpack/extract byte array element (e.g., -128, -12, etc.)` in order to capture the dataset values that were sent?

Comment: can you elaborate your question more..

Comment: You're going to have to find the *specification* of this protocol. You can't just guess it, and neither can we. Once you have it, you can use the various methods of `DataInputStream` to receive it.

Answer (score 0):

the question sounds very strange, if you have a byte array then there is not any problem to get the needed byte for its index, it you need get access to parts of bytes then as the first one you need find the specification of the protocol because without that you have not any idea about field lengths

p.s.

for bit parsing you can try [JBBP](https://code.google.com/p/java-binary-block-parser/)

Answer (score 0):

It is even more impossible, 500 does not fit into a byte.
To see regularities, you might puzzle with hex; that shows the bit packing (if that is the case);

```
int[] dataset = new int[5];
byte[] received = new byte[5];

dataset[0] = received[0];
dataset[1] = received[1];
dataset[2] = received[2] - (received[4] < 0 ? 0x7f : 0x80);
dataset[3] = 2;
dataset[4] = received[3];
if (received[4] < 0) {
    dataset[
    dataset[4] += 0x200; // 512
}
```

You really need more information. The above is an attempt to match both datasets to those received bytes, by minimal bits & operations. I would not bet for 1:100 that that is the correct decoding though.

Answer (score 0):

I modified my implementation to use DataInputStream to read data from socket as outline here:[Java TCP How do you read a sent stream size (header) and keep reading based upon that size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14776930/java-tcp-how-do-you-read-a-sent-stream-size-header-and-keep-reading-based-upon)
This approach provide flexibility to manipulate the various values such as individual header fields by using ByteBuffer

Thanks