# Determine packet size of TLS packet Java/Android

Tags: java, android, ssl, tcp

I have read all around the Stack, but I cannot find a working solution to determine the packet size and set the array of bytes to match that length to receive a correct amount of bytes for one message at once.

```
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
while(true) {
    short myShortStreamSize = in.readShort();
    byte[] payload = new byte[myShortStreamSize];
    in.readFully(payload);
    Log.i("Foo", new String(payload));
}
```

[That](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14777122) doesn't work for me.

My TLS server is made with Node.js. Normally Node.js TLS module handles the packets in the way if I use the same module to connect to the server it's enough to use `socket.write("message")` and the Node.js client understands the sizes already so you don't need to define it yourself. It will write that message to the console without issues. As I mentioned that my server is TLS. I'm not sure if these have something to do with my issue, but would be awesome to make it work.

My goal is to receive one message at once without cutting it into pieces. If I send "Good morning, today is a sunny day!" I want my Java/Android client to read it from start to end without mixing it up with other packets.

Comment: Did you try `while( (numBytes = read(payload)) >= 0 )` instead of your loop ?

Comment: Can you clarify?

Comment: @EugèneAdell Try it why? That will deliver the entire input stream, not a single message.

Comment: You're receiving a 16-bit length word, but are you sending that?

Comment: I tried to send many words, sentences, and stuff from the server, but the client doesn't get a message with the original code above. I can only get it to work with standard InputStream and removing all bytes that are 0 with a fixed size of the byte array. This seems to be the only way for me to get messages because dynamic packet size doesn't seem to work at all. With a dynamic, I mean that the client can calculate it's length before allocating the byte array.

Comment: I repeat. Are you sending a 16-bit length word ahead of every message? If you aren't, your code above doesn't make sense. And it is the simplest solution to your problem. All this stuff about null bytes isn't, unless, again, you are *sending* null bytes as message terminators *and* they don't occur inside messages.

Comment: Actually, when I read your latest response I believe I don't have sent such a word ahead of every message. I'm not yet sure should I be able to do that from the Node.js TLS server. I'm not familiar with it, yet. That explains why the DataInputStream doesn't work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ... size of TLS packet ... determine the packet size ... receive one message at once

There is no "TLS packet". There is a TLS record which has the length in the first 2 bytes. This TLS record might be split into multiple TCP fragments or TCP fragments might also contain multiple TLS records in full, in half or whatever. These TCP fragments then might even be cut into multiple IP packets although TCP tries hard to avoid this.

And your plain text "message" itself might end up being spread over multiple TLS records since the size of such a record might be smaller than the message. Depending on your application and TLS stack it might also be mixed together with other "messages".

In other words: what you want is impossible. Unless you somehow know already the size of your message before reading it you cannot rely on reading the full message and also only this message. Neither TCP nor TLS preserve any message "boundaries" you might have imagined when crafting your writes but which have no actual representation in the payload.

Comment: So the off-question comes here. How is the Node.js TLS Server & Client able to handle these packets in the way when I use `socket.write("message");` the client in Node.js can print out `message` on the console without empty bytes like `message♦♦♦♦♦♦♦♦`

Comment: @Divinar: Why should it print out empty bytes? It knows the number of bytes it has read (which is for example given in `onread`) and thus will print out only this number of bytes. But this has nothing to do with "packet" size.

Comment: Well. I mean it should not print out the empty bytes as it doesn't print them out on Node.js Server & Client. It seems that Logcat does so, empty byte will be ♦. So basically can I define a fixed byte size and then I just ignore the ♦?

Comment: Right now I get:

Yarr������������������������������ this unknown mark will come as long as the byte length is defined. Should I just ignore it? On Node.js I don't have such an issue.

Comment: You should try calling the right read method as I suggested before. `While true` loops rarely come from good tutorials.

Comment: @EugèneAdellnThe 'correct' read method you posted is considerably worse than the OP's original code, assuming he is sending a 16-but length word ahead of each message, which is moot.

Comment: If I iterate through bytes and remove bytes which are 0 is pretty much what I want, but I'm pretty sure that's not the correct way to do it. Edit: Actually not remove, but move that char to String if byte is not 0.

Comment: @Divinar SSL doesn't add any null bytes to your data, so here is no reason to believe that stopping at a null is correct. You haven't answered my question above.

Comment: These "null" or empty bytes come from a fixed byte array because the code above doesn't work. I just literally want to get rid of empty bytes and receive only the messages that are printed per line per message.

Comment: @Divinar I've told you why your code doesn't work. Stop fixating on these null bytes. They're only evidence of a problem.