# Handling TCP broken packets over a Secure connections (TLSv2) is failing because I can't see or decrypt content

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, client-server, tls1.2

**I am working on a client application that sends transactions to a server over a TLS connection. The applications sends a given number of bytes and receives 1182 bytes as response. It has been working fine until I started increasing the number of transactions per second**. After that, some response packets started to be broken and cannot be fully received by the client in only read. When I try to unwrap the packet content, it raises an exception and terminates TLS session.

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized record version (D)TLS-0.0 , plaintext connection?
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineInputRecord.bytesInCompletePacket(SSLEngineInputRecord.java:98)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineInputRecord.bytesInCompletePacket(SSLEngineInputRecord.java:64)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:544)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:441)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:420)
    at java.base/javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:634)
    at MyClass.handleEncryptedTransaction(MyClass.java:297)
```

I tried to use a buffer to accumulate possible broken packages, however I cannot see the packet content before decripting and can only estimate if it is complete based on its size.

```
    this.peerNetData.clear();
    int bytesRead = socketChannel.read(this.peerNetData);
    if (bytesRead == DEFAULT_TLS_HANDSHAKE_SIZE) {
        handleEncryptedTransaction(socketChannel, engine);
    } else if (bytesRead > 0) {
        // TLS packet buffering

        byte[] justRead = new byte[this.peerNetData.position()];
        this.peerNetData.flip();
        this.peerNetData.get(justRead);
        this.incompleteTransactionsBuffer.put(justRead);

        // DEFAULT_TLS_TRANSACTION_SIZE == 1182
        if (this.incompleteTransactionsBuffer.position() >= DEFAULT_TLS_TRANSACTION_SIZE) {
            this.incompleteTransactionsBuffer.flip(); // flipping to read mode

            while (this.incompleteTransactionsBuffer.remaining() >= DEFAULT_TLS_TRANSACTION_SIZE) {
                byte[] fullTransaction = new byte[DEFAULT_TLS_TRANSACTION_SIZE];

                this.incompleteTransactionsBuffer.get(fullTransaction, 0, fullTransaction.length);

                this.peerNetData.clear();
                this.peerNetData.put(fullTransaction);

                // This method uses this.peerNetData to unwrap data and 
                handleEncryptedTransaction(socketChannel, engine);
            }
            this.incompleteTransactionsBuffer.compact(); // wipe out bytes that had been read and free space of the buffer
        }
    }
```

**Is there anyway to check if a TCP packet over TLS is complete?** I tried to read the first 1182 bytes but it doesn't seem to work. **Interestingly, this code work when I get multiple packets in the response, such as (N * 1182), where N varies from 2 to 7**. Maybe I should wait for another socket read and get another piece of information?

I suppose this problem occurs because of packet retransmissions caused by heavy traffic. **Is there any other way to deal with TLS packet retransmissions in low level socket connections in Java?**

Comment: TCP does not have the concept of 'message' - it's just a stream of bytes (i.e. there's no correlation between the number of 'sends' and  the number of 'recvs' at the other end) - so if you want 'messages' you have to invent them.  TLS invents the 'TLS record' via a header which includes the length of the record. [See e.g. Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#TLS_record).  Your concern about 'retriansmissons' is wrong - TCP handles that, not layers above TCP.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I understood TCP is responsible for retransmissions and I don't need to handle this in the app. However, I do receive half of some TLS record on the way and can not identify it, that is the problem. For example: a TLS record I am waiting has 1000 bytes but I get only 700 bytes in the socket read. The last 300 bytes needs to be received on another read, but I can't know the size of the current TLS record. Is there any way to do it in Java?

Comment: As long as you've got the TLS header (a fixed size) you can find the TLS record length.  But in the cases I've seen, I think an SSLEngine is used to handle such details.

Comment: The error occurs exactly inside SSLEngine when I try to unwrap an amount of bytes I just read from socket. The SSLEngine returns an exception saying: "SSLException: Unrecognized record version" basically because the TLS record may be incomplete

Comment: If the SSLEngine needs more data it tells you, and then you have to read more data from the socket and give it to the SSLEngine.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk does the SSLEngine tells it by raising an exception? Or there is any way to check it before handling any exception?

Answer (score 1):

After getting comments and better understanding TLS protocol, I could work out a solution for the problem by implementing a buffer and getting the exact size of a TLS Record to wait for other TCP reads.

A TLS record "might be split into multiple TCP fragments or TCP fragments might also contain multiple TLS records in full, in half or whatever. These TCP fragments then might even be cut into multiple IP packets although TCP tries hard to avoid this.", from [Determine packet size of TLS packet Java/Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59189045/determine-packet-size-of-tls-packet-java-android). However, that post mentions first 2 bytes and it is not right. According to https://hpbn.co/transport-layer-security-tls/#tls-record-diagram:

> Maximum TLS record size is 16 KB
>
> **Each record contains a 5-byte header**, a MAC (up to 20 bytes for SSLv3,
> TLS 1.0, TLS 1.1, and up to 32 bytes for TLS 1.2), and padding if a
> block cipher is used.
>
> **To decrypt and verify the record, the entire record must be available.**

The TLS record size lies on the 3rd and 4th bytes:

[image: TLS Record Protocol]

The code ended up being like this:

```
protected synchronized void read(SocketChannel socketChannel, SSLEngine engine) throws IOException {

    this.peerNetData.clear();
    int bytesRead = socketChannel.read(this.peerNetData);
    if (bytesRead > 0) {
        // TLS records buffering
        this.peerNetData.flip();
        byte[] justRead = new byte[this.peerNetData.limit()];
        this.peerNetData.get(justRead);
        this.tlsRecordsReadBuffer.put(justRead);
        byte[] fullTlsRecord;

        // Process every TLS record available until buffer is empty or the last record is yet not complete
        while ( (fullTlsRecord = this.getFullTlsRecordFromBufferAndDeleteIt()) != null ) {
                this.peerNetData.clear();
                this.peerNetData.put(fullTlsRecord);
                handleEncryptedTransaction(socketChannel, engine);
        }
    } else if (bytesRead < 0) {
        handleEndOfStream(socketChannel, engine);
    }
}

private synchronized byte[] getFullTlsRecordFromBufferAndDeleteIt() {
    byte[] result = null;
    this.tlsRecordsReadBuffer.flip();

    if (this.tlsRecordsReadBuffer.limit() > DEFAULT_TLS_HEADER_SIZE) {
        // Read only the first 5 bytes (5 = DEFAULT_TLS_HEADER_SIZE) which contains TLS record length
        byte[] tlsHeader = new byte[DEFAULT_TLS_HEADER_SIZE];
        this.tlsRecordsReadBuffer.get(tlsHeader);

        **// read 3rd and 4th bytes to get TLS record length in big endian notation
        int tlsRecordSize = ((tlsHeader[3] & 0xff) << 8) | (tlsHeader[4] & 0xff);**
        // 0xff IS NECESSARY because it removes one-bit negative representation
        // Set  position back to the beginning
        this.tlsRecordsReadBuffer.position(0);
        if (this.tlsRecordsReadBuffer.limit() >= (tlsRecordSize + DEFAULT_TLS_HEADER_SIZE)) {
            // Then we have a complete TLS record
            result = new byte[tlsRecordSize + DEFAULT_TLS_HEADER_SIZE];
            this.tlsRecordsReadBuffer.get(result);
        }
    }

    // remove record and get back to write mode
    this.tlsRecordsReadBuffer.compact();
    return result;
}
```